# Implementation of Incremental conductance MPPT using cuk converter

Tags: microcontroller

does any one know how to track the incremental conductance MPPT in hardware using PIC microcontroller.

Comment: This is quite a broad question - a PIC will need external hardware to do it. Have you tried anything so far or is there a specific part you don't understand?

Comment: While the design considerations for a MPPT system could be on topic here, discussion of whether anyone knows about such things is off topic and pointless.  This question is clearly *not constructive*.

Comment: The most precise *answer* to this question that comes to mind is, "*Yes, someone does know*". :-)

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to have three distinct parts.

- Incremental conductance MPPT can use a range of converter types.
- CUK topology converters are one option.
- A PIC could be used for control purposes.

Your question should probably explain what you want to know about any of the above.

If you really mean "Can somebody give me finished code and circuits for xxx using a PIC" you should say so.

If this is a student project or assignment you should say so.

If you have particular reasons to specific incremental conductance you should say so.

If you don't know what it means you should come back after having found out.

---

The web seems to be awash with references to the use of CUK converters in this application. Information is not necessarily PIC specific but it is not especially conceptually complex to translate system specific requirements into PIC specific interfaces. If this is in fact a problem for you then you should say so.

To implement ICMPPT with a PIC you need a means of varying Voltage delievered to the load (in this case a variable voltage CUK converter) and a means of measuring load voltage and current. Once you have these the rest is "just engineering".

---

This paper provides only MATLAB and SUMULINK  results but does a better than usual job of explaining the elegant but simple Incremental Conductance MPPT method. Their explanation is good enough that I've included it below as an image.

[Implementation of Incremental Conductance MPPT with Direct Control
Method Using Cuk Converter](https://www.ijmer.com/papers/Vol2_Issue6/DP2644914496.pdf)

- ABSTRACT: This paper presents simulation of
  incremental conductance (IncCond) maximum power point
  tracking (MPPT) used in solar array power systems with
  direct control method. The main difference of the proposed
  system to existing MPPT systems includes elimination of the
  proportional–integral control loop and investigation of the
  effect of simplifying the control circuit. The resultant system
  is capable of tracking MPPs accurately and rapidly without
  steady-state oscillation, and also, its dynamic performance
  is satisfactory. The IncCond algorithm is used to track
  MPPs because it performs precise control under rapidly
  changing atmospheric conditions. MATLAB and SIMULINK
  were employed for simulation studies. Simulation results
  indicate the feasibility and improved functionality of the
  system.

The following image is copied from the reference above. Incremental Conductance MPPT is deceptively simple but very capable. It looks superficially like "hill climbing" MPPT but is not the same. Examination of the description and the cited paper is worthwhile for anyone interested in MPPT and not accustomed to the method.

[image]

---

This seems to exactly match your query. They do not use a PIC but their basic method could be directly translated into a PIC environment.

- [Incremental Conductance MPPT Method for PVS ystems](https://www.academia.edu/2182638/Incremental_conductance_MPPT_method_for_PV_systems)

Abstract - This paper presents incremental conductance methodfor maximum power point tracking (MPPT) using DC-DC cuk converter. Comprehensive analysis and simulation of KC85Tsolar module and equivalent electric circuit are provided while effects of various environmental conditions on the PV module behavior is investigated. In order to fully understand the PV module working specifications fundamental characteristics of PV cells are discussed. Block diagram model of a PV module was developed in Simulink for plotting the curves. KC85T solar module is used in simulations and results indicate speed and accuracy of the proposed system.

---

This paper provides an advanced implementation which varies the tracking step size for better tracking.   Details on reduction to hardware are minimal but given the basic system mentioned above you cpuld implement this system "with ease" [tm]

- [Advanced Incremental Conductance MPPT
  Algorithm with a Variable Step Size](http://pearlx.snu.ac.kr/Publication/JHLEE_2006_EPE.pdf)

Abstract—This paper proposes an advanced Incremental
Conductance MPPT algorithm with a variable step size for
a solar array regulator (SAR) system. This approach adjusts
automatically a step size to the solar array operating point,
thus improving the MPPT (Maximum Peak Power
Tracking) speed and accuracy compared with the
conventional method with a fixed step size. For the analysis
of stability of the proposed algorithm near the maximum
power point, the small signal modeling is carried out. Also,
it is verified by experiment using a 180W parallel connected
prototype hardware.

---

Here's the abstract for a for $ paper that looks rather apposite.
[Simulation and Hardware Implementation of Incremental Conductance MPPT With Direct Control Method Using Cuk Converter](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5456214)

- This paper presents simulation and hardware implementation of incremental conductance (IncCond) maximum power point tracking (MPPT) used in solar array power systems with direct control method. The main difference of the proposed system to existing MPPT systems includes elimination of the proportional-integral control loop and investigation of the effect of simplifying the control circuit. Contributions are made in several aspects of the whole system, including converter design, system simulation, controller programming, and experimental setup. The resultant system is capable of tracking MPPs accurately and rapidly without steady-state oscillation, and also, its dynamic performance is satisfactory. The IncCond algorithm is used to track MPPs because it performs precise control under rapidly changing atmospheric conditions. MATLAB and Simulink were employed for simulation studies, and Code Composer Studio v3.1 was used to program a TMS320F2812 digital signal processor. The proposed system was developed and tested successfully on a photovoltaic solar panel in the laboratory. Experimental results indicate the feasibility and improved functionality of the system.

---

And similar;

[Incremental conductance MPPT method for PV systems](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6030470/?arnumber=6030470)

- ABSTRACT
  This paper presents incremental conductance method for maximum power point tracking (MPPT) using DC-DC cuk converter. Comprehensive analysis and simulation of KC85T solar module and equivalent electric circuit are provided while effects of various environmental conditions on the PV module behavior is investigated. In order to fully understand the PV module working specifications fundamental characteristics of PV cells are discussed. Block diagram model of a PV module was developed in Simulink for plotting the curves. KC85T solar module is used in simulations and results indicate speed and accuracy of the proposed system.

Comment: Wow, that's one very long winded way to say *Yes, someone does know*.

Comment: @OlinLathrop Two men looked out through prison bars, one saw mud, the other stars - Perhaps from being struck while illicitly peering out :-) | 1. ICMPPT has enough to commend it that, even though it seemed likely the question 'would not get much traction' here, it seemed worth putting a body of ference re this method  of MPPT onto the site. It may yet be found by those who care more for MPPT excellence than linguistic pedantry, and can be re-used elsewhere if the need arises. 2. Google: "russell mcmahon" target_word and you'll oft find useful stuff. This adds to MPPT as target_word material.